# Does this reasoning about fourier analysis make sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-series

I'm asked to show that there cannot be $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t.

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|e^{it}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k\sin(kt)|^2dt=0$$

Here is my attempt:

Assume there are such $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\in\mathbb{C}$. The limit being $0$ would imply the convergence of $s_j=\sum_{k=1}^{j}\alpha_k\sin(kt)$ to $e^{it}$ in $\mathbb{L_2}(-\pi,\pi)$. If we now write $\beta_j=\frac{\alpha_j}{\sqrt\pi}$ we have $s_j=\sum_{k=1}^{j}\beta_k\frac{\sin(kt)}{\sqrt\pi}$. And since $\{\frac{\sin(kt)}{\sqrt\pi}\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $\mathbb{L}_2(-\pi,\pi)$ we know that we must have $\beta_k=<e^{it},\frac{\sin(kt)}{\sqrt\pi}>$. And after some work one find that $\beta_1=i\sqrt\pi$ and all other $\beta_i=0$. So that $s_j=\sum_{k=1}^{j}\beta_k\frac{\sin(kt)}{\sqrt\pi}=i\sin(t)\neq e^{it}$ which establishes the contradiction.

I think this is correct but I would like to be sure. Thanks

Comment: That's the idea, yes, I did not check your computations, though. You could also note that $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i\sin(t)$ and have now several possible lines of reasoning, e.g. $\cos$ not being in the (closure of the) span of the scaled sine functions, cause it's orthogonal to each of them. Depends on how much you already know about scalar product in Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realise that I could have reasoned like that, but I wanted to make things a bit more explicit to verify that I can apply this more 'basic' stuff as well.

Comment: Actually, the most basic argument may be orthogonality of $\cos(t)$ to the other functions because, if the $L^{2}$ norm of the difference converges to $0$, then $0=\lim_{N}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(t)\sum_{k=1}^{N}\Re a_{k}\sin(kt)\,dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^{2}(t)dt \ne 0$.